# Running Total ASP.NET MVC and Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.NET MVC2, SQLServer. I have 3 tables in my Database.

From `tblPerson` I am interested only in the `PersonID` field.
`tblPerson[PID(pk),PName]`

```
PID------------PName
12-------------AAA
13-------------BBB
```

`tblPHrs` has the following schema:
`tblPHrs[PId(pk),Semester(pk),Hrs]`

```
PID---------------Semester-----------Hrs
12----------------SS2011----------18
12----------------WS2012----------20
13----------------WS2011----------20
14----------------SS2012----------18
```

`tblCHrs` has the following schema:
`tblCHrs[CourseId(pk), PId(pk),Semester(pk), Whrs, UL, UT]`
here `WHrs`, `UL` and `UT` all are numeric field

```
CourseID-----------PId-----------Semester------WHrs----UL------UT
77-----------------12------------SS2011--------10------2-------1
78-----------------12------------SS2011--------4-------1-------2
79-----------------12------------SS2012--------24------4-------2
77-----------------12------------WS2012--------16------2-------2
77-----------------13------------SS2011--------4-------2-------2
```

Now I want to return this kind of result using LINQ to SQL by passing `PID` as a parameter for example `PID = 12`

```
Semester---PId--Hrs(from tblPhrs)--Acutal(tblChrs->summing(Whrs+UL+UT)--Gap--RngTotal
SS2011-----12---18-----------------20-----------------------------------2----0
SS2012-----12---20-----------------20-----------------------------------0----2
```

I'm using LinqToSQL, any idea how can I construct such query?

Comment: It's really hard to follow your question.  Can you clarify what you mean by 'UI+UT' and what fields those are or where they come from? What about 'Difference'? Could you format your question so that it's easier to follow? As it stands, I don't know where to begin to help you with your problem.

Comment: I agree with @GeorgeStocker , it's a little bit hard if you don't show the entire context

Comment: Sorry, actually i have 5 points and i am not allowed to post the images, i will edit my question now and hope it will be clear to understand

Comment: Use code blocks to make "ASCII-gaphics" - those require a fixed-width font in order to look correctly accross different browsers and platforms.